# Linearly dependent columns in the dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, dataset, data-preprocessing

I need to do the 'cleaning' of the dataset, ie preprocessing. I noticed that I have two columns in the dataset that are totally linearly dependent. Is it okay to delete one, both or am I not allowed to do any one that?

This is a school project and a ‘wild dataset’ where the emphasis is on a data processing. It's necessary to remove excess columns, detect anomalies, correlations between data, etc. Based on the first six parameters we predict the seventh column. If I understood correctly, based on these six parameters I should predict whether it will end up being the letter A, B or C? I mean, it's a matter of classification and not regression? Dataset has about 10.000 rows, here is the first 10, where we immediately see the relationship between the first and fifth columns, and my question is can I remove the fifth column in this case?

[dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3u95.jpg)

Comment: You are allowed to do whatever you want, they're your columns!! Now, if you delete both, you may lose information... but maybe that information is not relevant for your model, so you should delete them. Maybe they're relevant, but keeping one is enough. Maybe your model can learn something interesting by having both. This is unlikely if they're fully dependent, but there's a lot of witchcraft involved in ML.

Comment: Cross Validated is the appropriate place for questions on ML and Data Science.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I edited the post and hopefully the question is clearer now.